# Double-precision error using Dislin

Tags: function, graph, plot, fortran, double-precision

I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
 call qplot (Z, B, m + 1)
             1
 Error: Type mismatch in argument 'x' at (1); passed REAL(8) to REAL(4)
```

Everything seems to be in double precision so I can't help but think it is a Dislin error, especially considering that it appears with reference to a Dislin statement. What am I doing wrong? My code is the following:

```
program test

use dislin

integer :: i
integer, parameter :: n = 2
integer, parameter :: m = 5000
real (kind = 8) :: X(n + 1), Z(0:m), B(0:m)

X(1) = 1.D0
X(2) = 0.D0
X(3) = 2.D0

do i = 0, m
    Z(i) = -1.D0 + (2.D0*i) / m
    B(i) = f(Z(i))
end do

call qplot (Z, B, m + 1)

    read(*,*)

contains

real (kind = 8) function f(t)           
    implicit none
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: t
        real (kind = 8), parameter :: pi = Atan(1.D0)*4.D0  
            f = cos(pi*t)
end function f

end program
```

Comment: I think that with your compiler kind=8 is not double precision. Please try to use double precision or a select kind routine.

Comment: It's gfortran. I've written other programs in double precision with kind = 8. I tried using other statements and I get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It works and compiles.

Comment: Please don't alter the questions with noise like *solved*... Instead, accept an answer. Then, everyone can see that your problem is solved, and **how**. [As a nice side-effect, you will get shiny fake internet points for accepting an answer ;-) ] Also, please don't include tags in the title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [DISLIN manual](http://www2.mps.mpg.de/dislin/kap16.html#QPLOT) I read that `qplot` requires (single precision) floats:

```
 QPLOT connects data points with lines.

The call is:    CALL QPLOT (XRAY, YRAY, N)  level 0, 1
or:     void qplot (const float *xray, const float *yray, int n);

XRAY, YRAY  are arrays that contain X- and Y-coordinates.
N   is the number of data points.
```

So you need to convert `Z` and `B` to `real`:

```
call qplot (real(Z), real(B), m + 1)
```

Instead of using fixed numbers for the kind of numbers (which vary between compilers), please consider using the `ISO_Fortran_env` module and the pre-defined constants `REAL32` and `REAL64`.

Answer (score 1):

The qplot routine requires a default real. You can convert your data

```
 call qplot(real(Z), real(B), m + 1)
```

I second the remark with `kind = 8`, it is very ugly, if you insist on 8 at least declare a constant

```
   integer, parameter :: rp = 8
```

and use

```
   real(rp) ::
```

Answer (score 1):

As the first two answers explain, the standard versions of the dislin routines require single precision arguments.   I find it most convenient to use these since I may have single or double arguments, using the `real` technique to convert the type of double variables.  It seems unlikely that the lost precision will be perceptible on a graph.  However, if you wish to work exclusively in double precision, there is an alternative set of routines.  They have the same names, but take double precision arguments. To obtain them, link in the library "dislin_d".